# Where do I have to install Add-ons on Plone

Tags: plone, buildout, plone-5.x

I'm new on Plone, and I'm following [Plone Training](https://training.plone.org/5/index.html) tutorial. I'm trying Plone with Docker image from [here](https://github.com/plone/plone.docker/blob/master/5.2/5.2.0/debian/Dockerfile).

But in step 13, extending with new components, I don't know surely where I have to install the new packages, I try it on different sections:

buildout.cfg:

```
[plonesite]
  eggs =
    collective.easyform
    plone.app.mosaic

[instance]
  eggs =
    collective.easyform
    plone.app.mosaic

[versions]
  collective.easyform = 2.1.5
  plone.app.mosaic = 2.2.2
```

I can't get those packages appears on /@@overview-controlpanel to activate them.

Comment: Hi – please ask in our forum https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-run the buildout to get those new packages retrieved from PyPI and available. Also, don't forget to restart the Zope/Plone server.